# Trying to append data that doesn't exist in one table and into another in VBA and getting a syntax error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to use VBA to run an INSERT INTO ... SELECT query to append data that is not in one table and put it in my destination table.

I tried running the following query, but I'm getting a rather unhelpful syntax error (Error 3134) and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
    strSQL3 = "INSERT INTO IssuesDemo2" _
            & "([Provider Identifier]," _
                & "[Provider]," _
                & "[Caresite]," _
                & "[Care Address]," _
                & "[Bing Address]," _
                & "[Upload Date])" _
            & " SELECT" _
            & "TempTable.[Provider Identifier]," _
            & "TempTable.[Caresite]," _
            & "TempTable.[Provider]," _
            & "TempTable.[Address Composite (Caresite) (Care Site)] as [Care Address]," _
            & "TempTable.[Bing Suggested Postal Address (Caresite) (Care Site)] as [Bing Address]," _
            & "TempTable.[Upload_Date] as [Upload Date]" _
            & "FROM TempTable" _
            & "WHERE NOT EXISTS" _
            & " (SELECT 1 FROM IssuesDemo2 WHERE" _
                & "IssuesDemo2.[Provider Identifier] = TempTable.[Provider Identifier]" _
                & "AND" _
                & "IssuesDemo2.[Caresite] = TempTable.[Caresite]" _
                & "AND" _
                & "IssuesDemo2.[Care Address] = TempTable.[Address Composite (Caresite) (Care Site)]" _
                & ")"

db.Execute strSQL3, dbFailOnError
```

I have tried comparing my code to the sample code that I've seen here and on the internet, but I'm not seeing the source of the syntax error.  It executes successfully in a query builder in Access

Any help you can give is really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please print `strSQL3` before execution? Additionally, try to add one space before & after every append? Eg: `" WHERE NOT EXISTS "`

Comment: Definitely missing some spaces to prevent text running together when compiled.

Comment: @Govind it was the spaces.  I needed to add a space before and after each set of quotations, like your example above.  VBA is dumb and I don't know why that was a thing.  I owe you both dearly.

Comment: Also @June7 thank you too.